# Lua: How to make a lot of numbers to 1 variable

Tags: lua

```
local a= >3500
local b= 
local c= <3700
```

I don't know how I can make the 200 numbers in between into just the variable `b`

```
    lives=1


while lives > 0 do

math.randomseed(os.time())
local randomNumber1 = math.random(7200)
local randomNumber = math.random(randomNumber1, 7200)


print("Welcome to roulette!")




local a= >3500
local b= 
local c= <3700

local number1 = io.read()
local number1 = tonumber(number1)

if
    number1== a
    and randomNumber == a then
    print("You won!")
    print("Number was "..randomNumber..)

else if
    number1 == b
    and randomNumber == b then
    print("You won!")
    print("Number was "..randomNumber..)

else if
    number1 == c
    and randomNumber == c then
    print("You won!")
    print("Number was "..randomNumber..)

else
    print("Du tabte")
    print("Number was "..randomNumber..)

io.read()


lives=lives-1

end
```

Comment: you should rather do a Lua beginners tutorial.  this is very very very basic Lua.

Comment: your code doesn't make too much sense and is full of syntax errors. you should explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: yes you already said that. but what is number1 == b supposed to do, given that you want b to store 200 numbers. do you want to check if your number is in that interval?

Comment: and if you only bet on one number in roulette, there is only one way you can win. by hitting that number. so why do you need all those if blocks for? explain the rules of your "roulette" game

Answer (score 1):

You can use a numeric for loop for that. In order to store multiple values in one variable use a table.

```
local numbers = {}
local from = 3500
local to = 3699
for number = from, to do
  table.insert(numbers, number)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store multiple values in one variable.

You can store many values in a table and put that single table in a variable, or into another table if you want many tables stored in one place.

Comment: And how do i do that, and do i need to make giant tables with 3500 numbers in each